# How to use the Yahoo! JAPAN Japanese Language Processing API

Tags: yahoo-api

This is an example output of the `Furigana`

```
https://jlp.yahooapis.jp/FuriganaService/V1/furigana?grade=7&appid=xxxxxxxxxx&sentence=%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AA%E4%BA%A4%E3%81%98%E3%82%8A%E6%96%87%E3%81%AB%E3%81%B5%E3%82%8A%E3%81%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%82%92%E6%8C%AF%E3%82%8B%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%80%82%E3%81%AE%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A8%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%81%AB%E5%AF%BE%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9%E3%83%9D%E3%83%B3

{
    "xmlns": "urn:yahoo:jp:jlp:FuriganaService",
    "xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    "Result": {
        "WordList": {
            "Word": [
                {
                    "Surface": "漢字"
                },
                {
                    "Surface": "かな交じり"
                },
                {
                    "Surface": "文"
                },
                {
                    "Surface": "に"
                },
                {
                    "Surface": "ふりがな"
                },
                {
                    "Surface": "を"
                },
                {
                    "Surface": "振る",
                    "Furigana": "ふる",
                    "SubWordList": {
                        "SubWord": [
                            {
                                "Surface": "振",
                                "Furigana": "ふ",
                                "Roman": "hu"
                            },
                            {
                                "Surface": "る",
                                "Furigana": "る",
                                "Roman": "ru"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "Roman": "huru"
                },
                {
                    "Surface": "こと"
                },
                {
                    "Surface": "。"
                },
                {
                    "Surface": "の"
                },
                {
                    "Surface": "リクエスト"
                },
                {
                    "Surface": "に"
                },
                {
                    "Surface": "対"
                },
                {
                    "Surface": "する"
                },
                {
                    "Surface": "レス"
                },
                {
                    "Surface": "ポン"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "xsi:schemaLocation": "urn:yahoo:jp:jlp:FuriganaService http://jlp.yahooapis.jp/FuriganaService/V1/furigana.xsd"
}
```

and this the output of the `Conversion`:

```
http://jlp.yahooapis.jp/JIMService/V1/conversion?response=alphanumeric&appid=dj0zaiZpPVlyTjM3WGdlaXV3YyZzPWNvbnN1bWVyc2VjcmV0Jng9ZWM-&sentence=きょうはよいてんきです。

{
    "xmlns": "urn:yahoo:jp:jlp:JIMService",
    "xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    "Result": {
        "SegmentList": {
            "Segment": [
                {
                    "CandidateList": {
                        "Candidate": [
                            "今日は",
                            "きょうは",
                            "教派",
                            "興は",
                            "京は",
                            "強は",
                            "経は",
                            "教は",
                            "境は",
                            "凶は",
                            "卿は",
                            "峡は",
                            "協は",
                            "香は",
                            "恭は",
                            "享は"
                        ]
                    },
                    "SegmentText": "きょうは",
                    "Alphanumeric": "ｋｙｏｕｈａ"
                },
                {
                    "CandidateList": {
                        "Candidate": [
                            "よい",
                            "良い",
                            "宵",
                            "酔い",
                            "四位",
                            "４位",
                            "余威",
                            "好い",
                            "善い",
                            "佳い",
                            "吉い",
                            "快い",
                            "佳",
                            "可",
                            "嘉",
                            "儀",
                            "義",
                            "誼",
                            "吉",
                            "慶",
                            "好",
                            "淑",
                            "酔",
                            "善",
                            "良",
                            "俶",
                            "懿",
                            "譱",
                            "臧",
                            "醉"
                        ]
                    },
                    "SegmentText": "よい",
                    "Alphanumeric": "ｙｏｉ"
                },
                {
                    "CandidateList": {
                        "Candidate": [
                            "天気です。",
                            "転機です。",
                            "転記です。",
                            "転帰です。",
                            "天機です。",
                            "てんきです。"
                        ]
                    },
                    "SegmentText": "てんきです。",
                    "Alphanumeric": "ｔｅｎｎｋｉｄｅｓｕ．"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "xsi:schemaLocation": "urn:yahoo:jp:jlp:JIMService http://jlp.yahooapis.jp/JIMService/V1/conversion.xsd"
}
```

I have passed to the `Conversion` the parameter `response=alphanumeric`, that according to the docs should give me as output (if I have understood well) the
response type `roman`:

```
response    string: katakana, hiragana, alphanumeric, half_katakana, half_alphanumeric  通常のかな漢字変換のほかに、指定の変換候補を返します。複数指定できます。
"katakana": 全角カタカナ変換の内容をKatakanaに返します。
"half_katakana": 半角カタカナ変換の内容をHalfKatakanaに返します。
"hiragana": 全角ひらがな変換の内容をHiraganaに返します。
"alphanumeric": 全角英数字変換の内容をAlphanumericに返します。
"half_alphanumeric": 半角英数字変換の内容をHalfAlphanumericに返します。
無指定の場合は通常変換のみになります。
```

I have also tried the `mode` parameter

```
mode    string: normal, roman, predictive   かな漢字変換処理で通常変換、ローマ字変換、推測変換のいずれかを指定します。
"normal": 通常の変換候補を返す通常変換を行います。
"roman": ローマ字からひらがなに変換した結果のみを返すローマ字変換を行います。指定変換候補（response）、辞書指定（dictionary）は使用できません。
"predictive": 推測変換の候補を返します。指定変換候補（response）、辞書指定（dictionary）は使用できません。
無指定の場合は"normal"になります。
```

but I don't get the roman form

and the `format` parameter:

```
format  string: roman   "sentence"のテキストフォーマットを指定します。かな漢字変換の対象となるテキスト情報はひらがなのみとなります。 "roman"を指定すると、リクエストされたテキスト情報中のひらがなと半角英小文字が変換対象となります。
```

[http://jlp.yahooapis.jp/JIMService/V1/conversion?mode=roman&appid=xxxx&sentence=きょうはよいてんきです](http://jlp.yahooapis.jp/JIMService/V1/conversion?mode=roman&appid=xxxx&sentence=%E3%81%8D%E3%82%87%E3%81%86%E3%81%AF%E3%82%88%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E3%82%93%E3%81%8D%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99)。

```
{
    "xmlns": "urn:yahoo:jp:jlp:JIMService",
    "xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    "Result": {
        "SegmentList": {
            "Segment": {
                "SegmentText": "きょうはよいてんきです。"
            }
        }
    },
    "xsi:schemaLocation": "urn:yahoo:jp:jlp:JIMService http://jlp.yahooapis.jp/JIMService/V1/conversion.xsd"
}
```

How to return the standard / Hepburn Romanization?

Comment: For some crazy reasons I'm not able to edit this post (error: `the body cannot contains`) so I'm adding links to the Yahoo! Language Processing API here: `Conversion API` http://developer.yahoo.co.jp/webapi/jlp/jim/v1/conversion.html and `Furigana API`: http://developer.yahoo.co.jp/webapi/jlp/furigana/v1/furigana.html

Answer (score 1):

Furigana returns depending on the "Grade" level. 
Having it set to 7 only returns Furigana for High School level Kanji, and nothing lower than it. Removing the Grade or changing it to a lower level will return the resulting Furigana.